# Extracting parts of words from a file

Tags: list, vba, extract, ms-word, truncate

I have a list, "list A," containing tens of thousands of entries (4 example entries shown below).  I'd like to create from "list A" another list, "list B."  I need each entry of "list B" to contain only the 1st 4 (out of 5) characters of the 1st "word" following the ">" character that is at the start of each entry in "list A."

So, for example, I'd like a "list B" that looks like this:
2JUG
3JU9
1JU8
3JUE

I am new to script writing, and would appreciate any help you can offer.  The closest I got to solving my problem was printing the 1st column, but that gave me all 5 characters of my 1st "word," plus the long string of letters in the next line.  I am brand new to script writing, so if possible, please try to give me the "for dummies" version of your explanations.  Thank you!

***example entries from "List A" below***

> 2JUGA 78 NMR NA NA NA no TubC protein  [ANGIOCOCCUS DISCIFORMIS] || 2JUGB
>   GPLGSSAGALLAHAASLGVRLWVEGERLRFQAPPGVMTPELQSRLGGARH
>   ELIALLRQLQPSSQGGSLLAPVARNGRL
>
> 3JU9A 237 XRAY 2.10 0.207 0.253 no Concanavalin-Br  [CANAVALIA BRASILIENSIS] || 1AZDA 1AZDB 1AZDC 1AZDD 4H55A
>   ADTIVAVELDTYPNTDIGDPSYPHIGIDIKSVRSKKTAKWNMQNGKVGTA
>   HIIYNSVGKRLSAVVSYPNGDSATVSYDVDLDNVLPEWVRVGLSASTGLY
>   KETNTILSWSFTSKLKSNSTHETNALHFMFNQFSKDQKDLILQGDATTGT
>   EGNLRLTRVSSNGSPQGSSVGRALFYAPVHIWESSAVVASFEATFTFLIK
>   SPDSHPADGIAFFISNIDSSIPSGSTGRLLGLFPDAN
>
> 1JU8A 37 NMR NA NA NA no Leginsulin  [NA]
>   ADCNGACSPFEVPPCRSRDCRCVPIGLFVGFCIHPTG
>
> 3JUEA 368 XRAY 2.30 0.203 0.219 no ARFGAP with coiled-coil, ANK repeat and PH domain-containing protein 1  [HOMO SAPIENS] || 3JUEB
>   GPLGSGSGHLAIGSAATLGSGGMARGREPGGVGHVVAQVQSVDGNAQCCD
>   CREPAPEWASINLGVTLCIQCSGIHRSLGVHFSKVRSLTLDSWEPELVKL
>   MCELGNVIINQIYEARVEAMAVKKPGPSCSRQEKEAWIHAKYVEKKFLTK
>   LPEIRGRRGGRGRPRGQPPVPPKPSIRPRPGSLRSKPEPPSEDLGSLHPG
>   ALLFRASGHPPSLPTMADALAHGADVNWVNGGQDNATPLIQATAANSLLA
>   CEFLLQNGANVNQADSAGRGPLHHATILGHTGLACLFLKRGADLGARDSE
>   GRDPLTIAMETANADIVTLLRLAKMREAEAAQGQAGDETYLDIFRDFSLM
>   ASDDPEKLSRRSHDLHTL

Comment: Could you please provide a sample file - question formatting broke the input, and that's important for the possible solution.

Comment: Hi, Peter L.  Wow, thanks for your fast reply.  I'd be happy to provide the requested information.  Do you have an e-mail address to which I could sent the sample file?

Comment: P.S.  The formatting is that there are 2 lines per entry on the list.  The 1st line begins with ">abcde," and "abcd" is the information that I want.  The 2nd line is a long series of letters. Then there is an empty line, followed by the next entry on the list.

Comment: P.P.S.  I don't know if this is helpful, but another thought I had was to use the ">" for my script, but the ">" of ">abcde" that begins each entry is not unique to that starting position.  Some of the entries also contain this symbol at later points in the 1st line (though none of these ">" symbols are showing up in the original sample I posted).

Comment: Upload a file to dropbox or any similar filesharing service and drop a link here. If you don't have dropbox - install from here: http://db.tt/JNGZy87d

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w8q8avk139a9wwo/Z02X0EFWXH/listA.rtf

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w8q8avk139a9wwo/tpmyRX_VOZ/listB.rtf

Comment: I have a solution ready - are you familiar with VBA?

Comment: Hi Peter. Thank you! Can you teach me how this works? For example, what do the "^p>", "@@@>", and "^p" mean?

Comment: `^p` is a pattern for paragraph mark. 3 replacement cycles in code remove all extra line breaks except those which follow your desired symbols. `@@@>` means that specific symbols combination - actually, this is the trick where we may use ANY string which is NOT in the original document, and then back replace it to paragraph mark. The rest of code is a loop through every paragraph which cut off all but first 5 chars from its start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution - pretty straightforward, but will do the job assuming the input provided:

```
Sub NMRData()
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p>"
        .Replacement.Text = "@@@>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "@@@>"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p>"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    For k = ThisDocument.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set oPara = ThisDocument.Paragraphs(k)
        oPara.Range.Text = Left(oPara.Range.Text, 5) & vbNewLine
    Next k

    ThisDocument.SaveAs FileName:="listB.docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument

End Sub
```

Desired output will be saved in the same folder as a new DOCX file.

To run the code, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, and then <kbd>F5</kbd> - via VBA interface, or press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to select and run a Macro by name.

Sample DOCM with ready-to-go code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zt4nfn7rt8eqc7/NMRDataListA.docm

P.S. this is my very 1st Word-VBA experience)